# organise files based on words in the file and create a directory and put them in there

Tags: file, cmd

I have about a few thousand files in a folder. Each filename has a few different version's of the file so for example. tree.blue, tree.green, tree.orange, cat.black, cat.green,cat.white.

what i would like to do is have a .bat file to put all tree or any word before the "." to auto create a directory and add any file related to tree for example in it as well as for all the other filenames without specifying the word.Currently I have found code on here which almost does it but have to specify the keyword in the code for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each file is in the same format, something like this would work:

```
pushd "path_to_folder"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %%g in ('dir /b') do (
if not exist "%CD%\%%g" @echo md "%%g"
@echo copy "%CD%\%%g.%%h" "%CD%\%%g\%%g.%%h"
)
popd
```

You can remove the `@echo` once you confirm the system will be creating the right directory name and copying the files to the right location.

Comment: Hi, Copy pasted above code and saved as a .bat file but didn't work.  Next to pushd in " " I've also tried specifying the path but still didn't do anything can you advise?? Thank you!

Comment: @soyeb, I'd suggest turning echo on and seeing what error you are receiving. If the file names are not in the same format you provided in your example, this may also fail as well. If you can provide any error message and some exact file names, we can assist you further.